# Using UART to program a device with another sensor connected to the same UART - how to disconnect TX when the device is programmed?

Tags: circuit-design, design, uart

I have a device which I'd like to program without my physical presence.

The problem is when I connect TX, RX and GND to my device, a sensor which is connected to the device through the same UART is not working. I have to manually disconnect Device's TX <-> USB-UART converter in order for it to work.

I want to program the device and after that be able to receive data.

How can I detach my USB-UART converter's TX line?

I was thinking about making another device which would disconnect the line but I'm not sure what it should use? Maybe a simple transistor would be alright?

[image]

Comment: I think you need to show a schematic and explain what remote interface you plan on using when you are not at the location of your hardware.

Comment: Sharp X-acto Knife?

Comment: @Andyaka I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Using a spare IO line from the RaPi you could control an analogue switch that can be used to disconnect the sensor's TX line. It's a lot cleaner than using a transistor and you can get pretty small one from TI for instance. Don't forget to re-enable the sensor via the analogue switch when you have finished comms OR, if you want to make it more fail-safe in that respect use a monostable so that it automatically reconnects after a few seconds. To keep it disconnected for longer you would need to keep toggling the spare IO line (a bit like how a watchdog timer works).

Answer (score 0):

Yes what you proposed is possible. You will need a mechanism that sets the state of a one of the devices Output pin to tristate (either the USB or sensor).  This will cause the device's pin to be in a high impedance state which effectively allows you to remove it from the circuit.  You should also give the device some kind of ID and pass that along to allow the raspberry to know from which device it's coming from.